# Call a method from a UIAlertView Button

Tags: ios5

i created an Alert View that ask for some password but i´m wondering how to call a method only when the "Continue" button was clicked?

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)setUserAlert:(id)sender{

UIAlertView *setPassword = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Insert Password" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];

   //The password isn´t visible.
    setPassword.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
   [setPassword show];

    // Call the method that i want to call only after you click "Continue".
    [self displayMessage:(UIButton *)sender];
        }
    }
```

// Enable the button only when the length is >= 6 and password match

```
-(BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
//Defining the password 
NSString *password = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"12345678"];
UITextField *setPassword = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

  if ([setPassword.text length] >= 6 && [setPassword.text isEqualToString:password]){
    return YES;
  }
return NO;
}
```

// Action i want to call, after you click "Continue"

```
  -(IBAction)displayMessage:(UIButton *)sender{

  if ([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"YES"]){
    _user.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Hola Mony"];
    _imageUser.hidden = YES;
    _goodUser.hidden = NO;
    backgound.hidden = YES;
    yesButton.hidden = YES;
    noButton.hidden = YES;
    _userLabel.hidden =YES;
  }else{
    _user.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You can´t play"];
    _goodUser.hidden = YES;
    _imageUser.hidden = NO;
    yesButton.hidden = YES;
    noButton.hidden = YES;
    _userLabel.hidden =YES;
   }
}
```

I think to call "displayMessage" inside this one but i don´t know how to do it or if it´s correct.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
// the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
 if (buttonIndex == 1){
    // call displayMessage,  sends and error.  
 }  
}
```

Comment: You have to call in delegate method for your requirement. -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
Is your app will going crash. Then run once your app in debug mode then it will know isyour app crashing in the delegate method or in the displaymessage method

Comment: i fix it, forgetting the "displayMessage" method but maybe isn´t the best way to do it.                                                   - (IBAction)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 1){
        _user.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Hola Mony"];
        _imageUser.hidden = YES;
        _goodUser.hidden = NO;
        backgound.hidden = YES;
        yesButton.hidden = YES;
        noButton.hidden = YES;
        _userLabel.hidden =YES;
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the delegate is self, add the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method and determine if "Continue" was pressed by the index.